# Generar pdf desde una función de peticion POST, con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo la solicitud POST de un pdf:

```
Future<String> getData() async {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull(
          "www.example.com/post"),
      headers: {"Accept": "*/*"},
      body: {'code': '14499'});
  print(response.body);

  return "success!";
}
```

el cual me responde:

```
    I/flutter (10501): %PDF-1.3
    I/flutter (10501): 1 0 obj
    I/flutter (10501): [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
    I/flutter (10501): endobj
    I/flutter (10501): 10 0 obj
    I/flutter (10501): << /Length 5726 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream
    I/flutter (10501): X    ­\Ër#GvÝ;bþ!GãÆÓÅ|?ä'(¶Ð
```

Quiero visualizar el PDF que está retornando dicha función.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el pdf que esta retornado dicha funcion. Si print en la consola, mostrará el código del pdf. Si desea ver el pdf como pdf, debe mostrarlo en un view en su app. La forma más sencilla es utilizar una webview.

Primero agregue esta dependencia a su pubspec.yaml:

```
webview_flutter: ^2.3.1
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
    var pdf = 'https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf';
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: googleDocs + pdf,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Si desea guardar o editar el pdf, debe usar un paquete desde https://pub.dev. Si busca 'pdf', encontrará varios paquetes disponibles.

Comment: y como haría para enviar un solicitud post a una webview para que me responda con el PDF? como se envia peticiones http a un webview?

Comment: No necessita se envia un peticion http separada a un webview. Webview hace todo el trabajo cuando usa el codigo arriba. Si por alguna razón quiere enviar un peticion http, puede usa el codigo en su pregunta original.